# MYSQL: using des decrypt function with lower

Tags: mysql, encryption, mysql-logic

I have encrypted user data in my database using des_encrypt, now when i specify a particular statement as below:

```
SELECT LOWER( DES_DECRYPT( forename, 'ENCRYPT STRING' ) )
FROM Users
```

All the results are NOT returned in lowercase, anybody know what i am doing wrong? or perhaps how another way to do it?

p.s ENCRYPT STRING is a random character string, not the actual word. 
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: the LOWER( 'StRiNg' ) function in MySQL turns the string in its argument to lowercase. Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean that in my database there are forenames that are multiple case, (i.e upper and lower) and i want the string to be returned as lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
SELECT LOWER ( CONVERT ( DES_DECRYPT ( forename, 'ENCRYPT STRING' ) USING utf8 ) )
AS forename_decrypted FROM Users
```

The Lower-function can only convert strings, I don't know exactly if DES_DECRYPT returns a string or simply binary data..